# Creating parameter inside a plpgsql function to use in bash script

Tags: bash, plpgsql, psql

I have a plpgsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_function()
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$DECLARE
    export_time timestamp;
    export_path text;
begin
    export_time = now();
    -- copy the export datas into a csv file
    export_path = '/home/blabla/bla_' || (SELECT TO_CHAR(export_time, 'YYMMDD')) || '.csv';
    EXECUTE 'COPY (SELECT * blabla)
TO  '''|| export_path ||''' csv header;';
    END
$function$
;
```

Now I want to have "export_path" as a parameter inside a bash script when calling the function using:

```
#!/bin/bash
DB_NAME="blabla"
DB_USER="postgres"
psql -d $DB_NAME -u $DB_USER -c "SELECT test_function()"
chmod +x test_export.sh
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This won't work, since you are running bash as parent and psql as child. I don't know much about psql, but in theory, you have 4 possibilities: (1) Call the bash script from psql. (2) Define `export_path` as environment variable in bash and access it from psql. (3) Write the value of the path to a file and process the file afterwards. (4) Write the value of the path to stdout and collect the stdout in your bash script.

Answer (score 0):

After testing and just thinking until I pass out:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_function(export_path text)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$ DECLARE
    BEGIN
EXECUTE 'COPY (SELECT * FROM blabla) TO  ' || quote_literal(export_path) || ' csv header;';
    END;
$function$
;
```

In bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
DB_NAME="blabla"
DB_USER="postgres"
EXPORT_PATH="/home/blabla/bla_$(date +%y%m%d).csv"
psql -d $DB_NAME -U $DB_USER -c "SELECT test_function('$EXPORT_PATH')"
```